# Gnuplot persist graph windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, graph, charts, gnuplot

I am using the following commands to draw a simple `sin(x)` plot on gnuplot , with a pipe from VS2010 C++

```
set terminal windows
set title 'Graph of velocity versus time'
set xrange[0:10]
plot sin (x)
```

Problem is the window keeps closing down too quickly . I don't want to use the 'pause' command as it stop the entire code.

Is there any other way to keep this window open without the pause command?

Cheers

Comment: How do you open gnuplot?  If you're invoking gnuplot as `gnuplot`, can you try invoking it as `gnuplot -persist`?  or `gnuplot -`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant try it, but have you tried

1. setting the terminal to 'set terminal x11'
2. set up the terminal to multiple user screens by using 'set terminal windows 0'
3. set the output to a png or other image and then use the pipe to open am image viewer programm

The problem is that the command you set via your pipe is probably executed via cmd.exe which exits as soon as gnuplot return 1 (which is totally does after successful plot). With this the instance of the window is destroyed as well.

Comment: Toxicate80 - I dont have terminal x11 available apparently.

Comment: well in my windows version of gnuplot im able to change the terminal to x11. whatever that might imply

Comment: The problem seem that the -persist command is not being recognised or is not valid ....I am under the impression you could "plot sin(x) -persist" to plot the sin curve and keep the window open ...but it seems not to be working ...pause commands just hang my entire program so cannot be used really ...set terminal windows 0, also has no effect. This plots the graph but he window closes immediately

Comment: how would you do that or am I being stupid (i.e: set terminal to X11)