# Keep gnuplot plot window open after external execution with C#

Tags: c#, plot, process, gnuplot, continuous

What I am trying to achieve is a plot window that **updates continuously** (as my data file changes continuously) and stays open until I **manually close** it.

My gnuplot script ends with:

```
...
pause 0.5 
reread
```

If I call gnuplot with this script from the **command line**, it works **as expected**.

However, if I call gnuplot **through C#** and pass the identical script as an argument, the plot window **opens for 0.5 s and closes right after**.
I used the following bits of code to achieve this:

```
Process plotProcess = new Process();
plotProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"""C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe""";
plotProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
plotProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
plotProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
plotProcess.Start();
StreamWriter sw = plotProcess.StandardInput;
String strInputText = @"GNUPLOTSCRIPT;pause 0.5;reread";
sw.WriteLine(strInputText);                      
sw.Flush();                 
sw.Close();
```

Given that the gnuplot script works from the command line, I assume I am missing to call the correct extension method for *plotProcess*. To fix this, I tried (different orders of) the following

```
...
plotProcess.WaitForExit();
//sw.Flush();                 
//sw.Close();
```

which either doesn't help or freezes my process entirely until I have to kill it  from the task manager.
I am happy for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the "-persist", or shorter "-p", flag to the gnuplot command?
I.e.

```
plotProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"""C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe -persist""";
```

This should tell gnuplot to keep the plot window open even after the script has finished. Alternatively you could set the output in the gnuplot script to be persistent. See e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/a/906982) for more options.

Comment: If I pass `--persist` or `-p` like you suggested, the plot window won't show at all. 
I was aware of the options that were suggested in the post that you shared, Unfortunately, none of them work --- the plot window either doesn't show or closes right away. 

So far, I am able to keep the windows open for say 10 seconds by passing `pause 10`, then, however, the plot won't be updated as the file changes.

Comment: Does the persist option work if you call gnuplot outside of your c# program? This might be an issue with gnuplot in Windows, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13394526/9540286) or [this bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1145/). Both are pretty old, so I am just guessing that changing the terminal in gnuplot might help.

Comment: Yes, persist works outside of C#. I will see if the x11 terminal will help to fix the issue, it is however an annoying workaround and I think there should be a way to do this out-of-the-box.